# Show that there existe a unique holomorphic function $f : D(0; 1) \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, holomorphic-bundles

> Show that there existe a unique holomorphic function $f : D(0; 1) \to
>  \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(0)=0$ and $f'(z)=\frac{1}{1-z}$.

I think I can develop $\frac{1}{1-z}$ and look for the coefficient of the general term.

How could I do this quesiton? Any ideas?

Comment: How are the MacLaurin series of $f$ and of $f'$ related?

Comment: I know that for a power serie $\sum_{k \geq 0} a_k z^k$, $a_k = \frac{f^{(k)(0)}}{k!}$; related to taylor serie. This is what you mean?

Comment: Not quite. If $f(z) = \sum a_k z^k$ and $f'(z) = \sum b_kz^k$, how are the $a_k$ and the $b_k$ related?

Comment: $b_k = k a_k$, this is probably what you mean? thanks

Comment: Not quite, $b_k = (k+1)a_{k+1}$. So from the MacLaurin expansion of $f'$, you can obtain the MacLaurin expansion of $f$ - except for one coefficient, which you need to determine from the other constraints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $z\in \mathbb D$ implies $\text { Re }(1-z)>0.$ Thus $\log (1-z)$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb D,$ where $\log$ is the principal value logarithm.

Suppose now $f$ satisfies the given hypotheses. For $z\in \mathbb D,$ define

$$g(z) = f(z) + \log (1-z).$$

Then $g$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb D$ and for all $z\in \mathbb D,$

$$g'(z) = f'(z) - \frac{1}{1-z} = 0.$$

Thus $g$ is constant in $\mathbb D$and since $g(0)=0,$ $g\equiv 0.$ Thus $f(z) = -\log (1-z), z\in \mathbb D.$